# Access 2007: Can I use Format() in query Criteria?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, criteria

It seems I'm always trying to do the impossible. Well, I have a [month/day] table setup in the following format:

```
Noombers | Lemmas
-----------------
0101     | Jan 1
0102     | Jan 2
...      | ...
1230     | Dec 30
1231     | Dec 31
```

I have a table of [Publication Venues] with fields [Reads From] and [Reads To] that utilize this [month/day] table in that, when I enter the info, I just type in "Sep 1" and hit tab, which fills the field (in the background) with "0901". It's a text field because I want to sort alphanumerically and I also want to do an alphanumeric comparison. I thought I could do something like this in the Criteria for the query I've created for showing a list of publication venues that are currently reading:

```
Field:       Reads From              | Reads To
Table:       Publication Venues      | Publication Venues
Sort:       
Show:    
Criteria:    >Format(Date(),"mmdd")  | <Format(Date(),"mmdd")
```

But, though I am not seeing any errors, I am also not seeing the records that *should* be showing up. In fact, I'm not seeing any records.

So, is it safe for me to assume at this point that I can't use Format() in a query's Criteria? If so, then what is another way for me to go about setting up this filter? Using the table as I've already got it, preferably, since I've already got hundreds of records entered. If I can use Format(), then what do you suppose I'm doing wrong?

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Publication Venues].*
FROM
    [Publication Venues]
WHERE
    ((([Publication Venues].[Still Active?])=Yes)
  AND
    (([Publication Venues].[Reads From])<Format(Date(),"mmdd"))
  AND
    (([Publication Venues].[Reads To])>Format(Date(),"mmdd")));
```

Comment: Can you show the actual SQL of the query you are using?

Comment: @HelloW, okay. I've updated the original post with the SQL.

Comment: No wait, the Format() does work. It's my logic that's off.

Answer (score 1):

You see no errors because what you are doing does not cause any errors. However, it does not work as you expect.

If you are storying your dates as 4 numbers Access does not inherantly know how to interpret that. For instance, 1231 converted to a date, is May 15th 1903.

To use the format that you are using you would need to do `>Format(Date()-40043,"mmdd")` and `<Format(Date()-40043,"mmdd")` to make up for the difference.

More likely you'll want to convert your 4 digits into a date something like this:

`Cdate(Left$([Reads From],2) & "/" & Right$([Reads From],2) & "/" & Year(Date()))>Date()`

Long story short, you should store dates as dates if you want to use them as date. Otherwise you have to jump through some hoops so that your front end knows you're dealing with dates.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, and I thank you for it, but for some reason my brain can't seem to follow this. Needless to say I have a lot to learn, but I have managed to come up with something my brain can follow, which I'll post as the answer. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be the solution, at least for the way my brain works:

```
SELECT [Publication Venues].*
FROM [Publication Venues]
WHERE
   ((([Publication Venues].[Still Active?])=Yes)
AND
   (((([Publication Venues].[Reads From]) < ([Publication Venues].[Reads To]))
   AND
   (Format(Date(), "mmdd") BETWEEN ([Publication Venues].[Reads From]) AND ([Publication Venues].[Reads To])))
OR
   ((([Publication Venues].[Reads From]) > ([Publication Venues].[Reads To]))
   AND
   (Format(Date(), "mmdd") NOT BETWEEN ([Publication Venues].[Reads From]) AND ([Publication Venues].[Reads To]))))
);
```

I appreciate your help, people. Your feedback did get my mind working in a direction that lead me to a solution.

Comment: +1 That does look to be a simple enough solution, however I can't help noticing you are not including years in the values. Is that never likely to be a problem after say 1 year has passed or will you not need to go back beyond the current year, something to keep in mind : )